# How to insert `<span id="myspanid"></span>` to all content between html tags?

Tags: javascript, html

Fore example, I want to change

`<h1>content1</h1><p>content2</p>`

to

`<h1><span id="myspanid">content1</span></h1><p><span id="myspanid">content2</span></p>`

I prefer to do this at server side with php.

Comment: Element IDs must be **unique**. Use `<span class="myspanid">...</span>` instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/):

```
$('body *').wrap('<span class="foo"></span>');
```

If you're not (to fix [@minitech's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657721/how-to-insert-span-id-myspanid-span-to-all-content-between-html-tags/5657790#5657790)):

```
var elts = document.body.childNodes,
    numElts = elts.length,
    elt;
for(var i = 0; i < numElts; i++) {
    elt = elts[i];
    elt.innerHTML = '<span class="foo">' + elt.innerHTML + '</span>';
}
```

Comment: Can you show me how to do this on a str? The input str is the original content, and output is the new formatted?

Comment: What do you mean "do this on a string?"

Comment: Dunno why that has upvotes, it's plain wrong. It will wrap *all* elements in a span, creating invalid HTML (*<span class="foo"><h1>content1</h1></span><span class="foo"><p>content2</p></span>*) and ignore textNodes that are children of the body and do weird things with nested elements - try it on a table. Also, the OP wants to pass a string (presumably an HTML fragment).

Comment: @RobG: thanks, you're completely right. I was not awake when I wrote this last night. At any rate, the OP has added this to the question since then: _"I prefer to do this at server side with php."_

Answer (score 1):

Don't use innerHTML the way suggested in other answers, it will mess with whatever else you have in the element. You need to look for text nodes and wrap them, like this:

```
// Pass either an id or a DOM element
var wrapContent = (function() {

  // This could be passed as a parameter
  var oSpan = document.createElement('span');
  oSpan.className = 'mySpanClass';

  return function(id) {
    var el = (typeof id == 'string')? document.getElementById(id) : id;
    var node, nodes = el && el.childNodes;
    var span;
    var fn = arguments.callee;

    for (var i=0, iLen=nodes.length; i<iLen; i++) {
      node = nodes[i];
      if (node.nodeType == 3) {
        span = oSpan.cloneNode(false);
        node.parentNode.insertBefore(span, node);
        span.appendChild(node);
      } else {
        fn(node);
      }
    }
  }
}());
```

If you want to run it on a string of HTML, then create a div, insert the string as its innerHTML, run the above function passing it the div, then grab the innerHTML back:

```
function wrapHTMLstring(s) {
  var el = document.createElement('div');
  el.innerHTML = s;
  wrapContent(el);
  return el.innerHTML;
}

alert(wrapHTMLstring('<h1>content1</h1><p>content2</p>'));"
// <h1><span class="mySpanClass">content1</span></h1><p><span class="mySpanClass">content2</span></p>
```

Note that the childNodes collection will differ in different browsers for the same HTML if you have any extra whitespace, so you may need to do some processing there (e.g. if a textNode doesn't have any content, don't wrap it).

Answer (score 0):

If you're not (fixed to 'do it on a string', hopefully):

```
var b = document.body.childNodes;
for(var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
     if(b[i].nodeType === 1) {
         b[i].innerHTML = '<span class="foo">' + b[i].innerHTML + '</span>';
     } else if(b[i].nodeType === 3) {
         var newElement = document.createElement('span');
         newElement.className = "foo";
         b.replaceChild(newElement, b[i]);
     }
}
```

Comment: That would clobber the existing content.

Comment: <testtest [testtest](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/13221249#13221249) -delete when you're done with it :)-